# Apache2 Graceful Loads Different php.ini

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I have an apache server running Apache/mod_php.

On Fresh start and when using sudo service apache2 restart the correct php.ini file is loaded:

[image]

Doing a graceful reload of apache i.e "sudo service apache2 graceful" results in php loading a different php.ini (which is non-existing on filesystem):
[image]

What could be causing this and any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe if you should rather [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), the guys might know. It is at least weird.

Comment: Already asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646764/apache2-graceful-loads-different-php-ini.

Comment: Hi @Froggiz I was explicitly told by a moderator on StackOverflow to re-post on ServerFault hence why I have added here as well.

Comment: The stackoverflow answer look like correct check if /php.ini exist

Comment: I have verified that this file does indeed not exist. But even if it did, why does PHP pick up a different php.ini on full restart v. graceful reload?

Comment: Those screenshots are taken within the same minute, possible within seconds from each other. Perhaps the graceful restart wasn't completed yet, and later the correct config shows?

Comment: Hi JayMcTee, I wish that were the case but unfortunately not. The incorrect values persist.

Comment: It's loading `/php.ini` from the configuration path `/etc/php5/apache2`, which is the same file as `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` according to how I read the information. No Problem.

Comment: Wurtel, thats how i initially read it too but I was able to verify this is not the case.

1. The configuration values are not the values I have in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.
2. I created a symbolic link from /php.ini -> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and it loads the correct config values.

It is definitely trying to load /php.ini and the file definitely does not exist. Thanks for all the ideas so far everyone.